# MySQL stored function with table

Tags: mysql

I've the following result returned by a mysql function named `GetFamilyTree`

```
565,586,579,587,596,591,594,595
```

and another table named `salary` contains the following

```
+------+-------+
| uid  | sal   |
+------+-------+
|  565 | 10000 |
|  568 | 20000 |
|  587 | 15000 |
|  595 |  7000 |
|  596 | 40000 |
+------+-------+
```

I need the total salary of all the members.

I do not want to use a temporary table.

I've tried the following so far without success

```
select sum(sal) from salary where uid in (select GetFamilyTree('550'))
```

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a set of values are in the form of a CSV, then you need to use `find_in_set`. Values must be separated only by a comma and nothing else.

Try this:

```
select 
  sum(s.sal) total_salary
from 
  salary s, 
  (select GetFamilyTree('550') as ftree) as t 
where 
  s.uid find_in_set( s.uid, t.free )
```

**Refer to**:

- [**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d75cf2/1)
  I have used return string of your function `GetFamilyTree('550')` for demo.
- [**FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
  Return the index position of the first argument within the second argument.